# Jquery create new object out of DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, out

Hello Im relative new into JQuery... more used to PHP
Its just really simple I think but Im too stupid and if im honest JS cracks my mind....(in OOP Ive to learn much too...)

So I already found out that there arent arrays like in PHP.

Ok lets start.

My HTML Looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <ul id="ul_1"></ul>
    <ul id="ul_2"></ul>
    <ul id="ul_3"></ul>
</div>
```

And now I want to generate this out of that anyway

```
controller = {
    "#ul_1": 1,
    "#ul_2": 1,
    "#ul_3": 1
};
```

So to be more precise, at moment its hard coded like the code example above this line.
But I want that it generates automatically out of the HTML or better DOM.

I already tried `.map`, `.find` and `.each`... but im too disabled.

I always prefered it make it at once, so I mean no iteration with `.each` if that would be possible. I think maybe its possible to create a new object out of the `$.('#content')` object but in the style I need it.

Thank very much you Rycochet

heres **the solution** for my case

```
var controller = {};
$("#content > ul").each(function (i, el) {
    controller['#' + $(el).attr('id')] = 1;
});
```

Is there another solution, too? Like with .map or is that the best, fastest and easiest way to do it?

Comment: I don't see how the keys and values in your object relates to the HTML you gave?

Comment: In your HTML there is no such ID as `#product`, `#staff` or `#isn`...

Comment: True, true! Sorry I changed only the half....Ill fix it

Comment: When I find the edit button....?

Comment: now its correct or better said so like I wanted it from beinning..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally guessing here - but if your data is something like this -

```
<div id="content">
    <ul id="ul_1">
        <li>isn</li>
        <li>staff</li>
        <li>product</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can make such an object by -

```
var controller = {};
$("#ul_1>li").each(function(i, el) {
    controller[$(el).text()] = 1;
});
```

As the comments above say - you've not put enough details for more than a guess though.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I got it with your method!